# TableView in UIViewController moves to sides inside the window

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, autoresize

I've just put a `TableView` inside a `UIViewController` and embedded `ViewController` in `NavigationController` via the storyboard. I implemented delegate & source methods and everything works fine except when I load the view in *landscape* mode for the first time and then change it to portrait mode. `TableView` could be moveable to the sides outside of the window and it stays, but it is not sticking to edges.

[image: Screenshot of the issue described above.]

PS: This is designed for use on iPad.

edit: added another ss : http://d.pr/i/vs5d

Comment: It probably has something do you with how you are using autolayout or your struts and springs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer; need to reload the tableview after orientation change. I guess it's an auto layout bug that happens after landscape->portrait orientation change.

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```